# g++ linking a static library error

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm mostly used to working in the Visual Studio 2013 environment. I need to use this library in a project that I'm working on:
https://github.com/s3rvac/cpp-bencoding

**My first question is:** Does it matter if I build the library in Visual Studio or GCC (MinGW-w64)?

Anyway, I built it using GCC (4.9.2) since the author did so in his instructions on GitHub. I got no errors and I produced a library called **libbencoding.a**

Now I want to link this lib-file to my own project. This is were I get stuck. So I created a simple hello world program (main.cpp). The location of libbencoding.a is in the folder **C:\...\cpp-bencoding\build\src**

```
g++ main.cpp -L "C:\...\cpp-bencoding\build\src" -l libbencoding -o foo.exe -std=c++11
```

However this produces the error message:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-4.9.2-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot
 find -llibbencoding
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-lencoding`, without `lib`

Comment: `-lbencoding` actually.

Comment: people correct me if I'm wrong but for your question if it matters with which compilers the library has been compiled,  yes. because C++ does not have a stable and standard ABI , for example if your library's source code define the class Foo with method bar, g++ may put the name class__foo__method__bar in the library binary,  and when doing the linking maybe the visual compiler looks for  method__bar__of__class__foo

Comment: Thanks for the comments, now I get it and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your project compiled and linked using Visual Studio 2013, you project can have compilation and link error in MinGW, because they implement different set of C++ standard or if you use non-standard language features.

As allan.simon mention, you can't use .a library in program compiled with Visual Studio and vice versa because of lack of standard ABI (it is possible only if you use C compiler).

The project cpp-bencoding uses CMake, so you can try compile it using Visual Studio.

One more thing, when you use MinGW, the order of libraries matter. You can compile project with options `-lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3` using Visual Studio, but MinGW can give you link errors (undefined references).

The details you can find [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, indeed I used Cmake to generate a VS2013 project and I compiled it without any errors. However, I couldn't link the resulting bencoding.lib file to my other Visual Studio project.

Comment: @DoubleTrouble, try to use `#pragma comment(lib, "C:\Path\to\lib\bencoding.lib")` in your source code that uses bencoding. Specify full path to .lib file (just for test only).

Comment: I did try exactly that before I switched to GCC without success. I wasn't very confident that it was supposed to work, but now I might give it another try

Comment: I'm not sore about slashes in path. Anyway, you can modify options in Visual Studio 2013: Right click on project in visual studio, select Properties menu, than select Linker option in the left side, add path to folder with bencoding.lib (C:\Path\to\lib\) in Additional Library Directories. Than in left side select Linker->Input menu, and add `bencoding.lib` in Additional Dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried that as well (that is the standard way for me)